# Specific port of Azure SQL Database Serverless

Tags: azure-sql-database

The security rule of our company requires us to change the port from 1433 to another.
But is it possible to change the port for **serverless** SQL?
I search a bit and it seems only applicable for independent SQL Server instances.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot specify ports for Azure SQL Database, serverless or otherwise.  You can specify the port for SQL Server in an Azure VM since you have complete control over the instance.

You should configure the Azure SQL Database Firewall to only accept incoming connections from specific IP Address ranges.  This prevents unwanted connections to your database.

Azure SQL Database uses port 1433 to establish connections via the Azure Gateway however the particular SQL Server instance that the database is running on at will actually be using a dynamically chosen port which can change as the database moves between instances.

Take a look at [this Microsoft TechCommunity article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/datacat/connect-to-azure-sql-database-v12-via-redirection/ba-p/305362) for more details.

Comment: Is there a minimum price tier that allows forcing 1433 as a static port? Serverless generally means having no control over the config, but this is a nice to have as an option?

Comment: You'd need to setup an Azure VM to choose your port.